# What does "past painted" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "Past painted" mean? I saw this in the Paul McCartney's song "Mull of Kintyre":

> Past painted deserts the sunset of fire

Comment: When you cut it out of context, it doesn't mean much. _Past_ means the same here as in "I walked past a house", which becomes clear when you look at the context: _Far have I travelled [... p]ast painted deserts_ So as he travelled, he passed by painted deserts. This is not the place for interpretation of musical lyrics or  poetry though.

Comment: Interpretation of lyrics is OT. This Q may be closed.

Comment: There are no ' sunsets of fire', the sun *sets* the desert on fire, the lyric is 'the sun sets on fire',

Comment: I think Spagirl's correct and I also think although it's in a clear minority of the lyric sites, the line should be *Vast…* not *Past painted deserts…*

Whatever Paul sounded like, *Past…* is not and *Vast…* is supported by the wordds, the flow and the rhythm of the song…

Comment: @Spagirl it is, *past painted deserts **the sunset's on fire***

Answer (score 0):

According to *Lyrics (Songbook): Complete Lyrics for Over 100 Songs from Broadway to Rock* ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=tdjLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT765&dq=mull+of+kintyre+lyrics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv5sPLyp3bAhUEI6wKHazLCQkQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=mull%20of%20kintyre%20lyrics&f=false)) the actual lyrics are copyright 1978 and say

> Far have I travelled and much have I seen
>   Dark distant mountains with valleys of green.
>   Past painted deserts the sunset's on fire
>   As he carries me home to the Mull of Kyntyre.

The third line means, simply

> The sunset's [the sunset is] on fire past painted deserts

with *past* meaning *on the further side of* (preposition, [Oxford 1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/past))

Note that there is a difference between saying/singing *the sun sets on fire* and *the sunset's on fire*, and it is the latter that Paul sings.

A fiery sunset is what "paints" deserts.

Answer (score -1):

I think it has nothing to do with past in the sense of history, because then Paul would sing: "Paast instead of pest". He is an Englishman and not an American. I think he talks about a kind of color: pastel.